# Adding min/max images to NSSlider using Swift

Tags: swift, nsview, nsimage, nsmenu, nsmenuitem

I created a NSSlider programmatically and implemented it in a NSMenuItem:

```
    let menuVolumeSliderItem = NSMenuItem()
    let menuVolumeSlider = NSSlider()

    menuVolumeSlider.sliderType = NSSliderType.linear
    menuVolumeSlider.isEnabled = true
    menuVolumeSlider.isContinuous = true
    menuVolumeSlider.action = #selector(AppDelegate.doSomething)
    menuVolumeSlider.minValue = 0.0
    menuVolumeSlider.maxValue = 1.0
    menuVolumeSlider.floatValue = 0.5
    menuVolumeSlider.frame.size.width = menu.size.width
    menuVolumeSlider.frame.size.height = 20.0

    menuVolumeSliderItem.view = menuVolumeSlider
    menu.addItem(menuVolumeSliderItem)
```

And essentially, it work’s like a charm:

[image]

But the result I want to achieve is a Slider with a min/max image on the left/right edge of the Slider like this one:

[image]

How can I achieve a NSMenuItem like that?

**EDIT:**

I’ve created a custom NSView:

```
    let view = NSView()
    view.frame.size.width = menu.size.width
    view.frame.size.height = 25.0
```

... then created a NSImage ...

```
    let img = NSImageView()
    img.frame.size.width = 16.0
    img.frame.size.height = 16.0
    img.image = NSImage(named: "NSStatusAvailable")!
```

... and added `menuVolumeSlider` and `img` to my custom view:

```
    view.addSubview(img)
    view.addSubview(menuVolumeSlider)
    menuVolumeSliderItem.view = view
    menu.addItem(menuVolumeSliderItem)
```

... and it worked! But can anyone please give me a hint how to change the positions of the subViews?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a NSView that will include the slider and the two images. Then set menuVolumeSliderItem.view to be that NSView.

Comment: Play with this approach, what will happen if you add only the slider to the view, still hidden? Maybe change the slider width to fit the view better? Play with it and try to understand why it is not showing, however, this is the approach and the direction you should take. @ixany

Comment: Hey Roy, thanks for your help, really appreciate it! I could solve the  problem. Would be great if you could also give me a hint how to change the positions of the subViews. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Set frame to the slider and set its size and origin relative to the menu item nsview:

let menuVolumeSlider = NSSlider.init(frame: NSRect(x: positionX, y: positionY, width: Width, height: Height))